# Почему не могу добавить элемент из вектора в вектор?

Tags: c++, ооп, stl

```
vector<int>v1{ 54,54,546,65,5,5454,35,7 };
vector<int>v3{};
for (auto it : v1)    //ни так
    v3.insert(it);
for (auto i = v1.begin(); i != v1.end(); ++i)    //ни так
    v3.insert(*i);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, `insert` для вектора требует два параметра - **куда** вставлять, и **что** вставлять. Вы передаете только **что**.

Во-вторых, вообще не используйте `insert` с вектором - кроме самых крайних случаев... ограничивайтесь `push_back()`.

И вообще, в вашем конкретном случае достаточно простого присваивания -

```
v3 = v1;
```

Если позарез хочется `insert` - то тогда уж лучше

```
v3.insert(v3.end(),v1.begin(),v1.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

Метод insert требует указания куда вставлять элемент. Если добавлять нужно в конец:

```
vector<int>v1{ 54,54,546,65,5,5454,35,7 };
vector<int>v3{};
for (auto it : v1)    
    v3.push_back(it);

for (auto i = v1.begin(); i != v1.end(); ++i)  
    v3.push_back(*i);

for (auto it : v1)  
    v3.insert(v3.end(), it);
```